# Interchanging supremum with expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

I know we don't have an equality $\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E} f(X,y) =  \mathbb{E} \sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}}f(X,y)$ in general. But how about a simpler case, namely, is equality

$$\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E} \sum_{k=1}^nX_kf(ky) = \mathbb{E}\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}}  \sum_{k=1}^nX_kf(ky)$$

true, where $f$ is some nice, bounded and continuous function, and $X_k$ are Bernoulli r.v.?

Comment: You can see: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2230255/1231520  and https://mathoverflow.net/q/107887/521626

Comment: There are only two classic theorems that come to mind: dominated convergence and monotone convergence. Hint: you said that $f$ is bounded.